# How to implement thread safety aside from atomicInteger in java

Tags: java, concurrency

Currently I'm new to Java concurrency. and I'm having a hard time to find another way to
thread safe the process method without setting the counter into atomicInteger? If I try to put synchronize on process method it will eliminate the concept of concurrency.

I appreciate any help thanks!

```
public class SingleThread {
      private static int counter;

      public static void process() throws InterruptedException {

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
          counter++;
          Thread.sleep(1);
        }

      }



      public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // START of workable area
        int numThreads = 5;


        List < Thread > threads = new ArrayList();

        for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
          var thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
              try {
                process();
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
              }

            }
          });

          thread.start();
          threads.add(thread);

        }

        for (Thread thread: threads) {
          thread.join();
        }

        // END of workable area
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Time: " + (end - start) + " ms");
        System.out.println("Data Count: " + counter);
      }


    }
```

Comment: Each thread could have its own counter, and then when you join them all you could sum them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `synchronized` block, instead of putting it on the entire method.

```java
public static void process() throws InterruptedException {

  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    synchronized (SingleThread.class) {
      counter++;
    }
    Thread.sleep(1);
  }

}
```

Comment: Wow! It works! So basically when you enclose it with synchronized, each thread will have its own counter? correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @kelsky No, there is only one counter, since it is `static`, but only one thread can execute the code in the `synchronized` block at a time, so there is no race conditions messing up the incrementing of the value.

Comment: thank you so much! I appreaciate it!